# Giving an admin user access to log files (like root would have) on Linux

Tags: linux, security

I've just got a new dedicated server and have gone around setting up basic security on it.

Relevant securities I have added:

- Can only login via private key
- Changed ssh port
- root cannot login via ssh, created admin user "james" <-- my main issue involves this

I login as "james", who is a member of the "admin" group. I can do anything on this account, but I **can't** do the following:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

I can't access the `access.log` file, even though I thought (because I'm an admin) I should be able to do this.

How can I give "james" direct access to these files, and others that require root access, without having to `su` to root all the time (I'd like to disable this) and without changing permissions to 777 (death)?

Comment: `sudo` is your friend.

Comment: @dawud I can't `sudo cd` to a directory unfortunately... I can't read anything within the directory.

Comment: @Jimbo You can `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log` just fine. Also, a shortcut for `su` is `sudo su`

Comment: @NathanC Ah, so it does. Only annoying thing is I can't `tab` to list files in the directory - thanks though! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the log has permissions that look something like this:

> -rw-r--r--  1 root root 580700 Aug  1 10:53 access_log

You could change the group access to the admin group by issuing a command such as:

```
sudo chown root:admin /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Resulting in

> -rw-r--r--  1 root admin 580700 Aug  1 10:55 access_log

This would allow someone belonging to the admin group read permissions on the log.

Comment: What happens when the log rotates and a new access.log is created?

Comment: If you're using `rotatelogs`, you can tell it how to set the permissions.

Comment: Here are the defaults: -rw-r-----  1 root adm  [date] access.log. Also, is it secure and okay to be doing this, or is it generally frowned upon as logs need to be pretty secure

Comment: @Flup I was trying to get OP to think about it and include it in the answer. :)

Comment: For future users: This was owned by the **adm** group, so I changed this to **admin** and all is good. More [here](http://superuser.com/questions/86347/whats-difference-between-group-admin-and-adm). An alternative is to add your user to the adm group.